# A word after function arguments braces

Tags: functions, espressif

I'm just reading through a header files for task code in ESP8266 SDK.

I found this line and wondering what does the word `PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION` after the function arguments braces means ?

```
void vTaskDelay( const TickType_t xTicksToDelay ) PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION;
```

`PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION` is defined here, but why it's used after the function braces ?

```
/* Ensure API functions go in the privileged execution section. */
#define PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION __attribute__((section("privileged_functions")))
#define PRIVILEGED_DATA __attribute__((section("privileged_data")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's impossible to tell without looking in the source code for that SDK.

However it will just be a pre-processor macro which probably expands out to one or more *attributes*, some of which may be specific to the XTensa LX106 compiler.

---

Update after your edit:

It places the function in the `privileged_function` section. That section is then placed into a specific area of memory by the linker.

To further examine what it does you will have to look in the linker script to see how it handles that section, and what that means from the chip's perspective, by cross-referencing that with the chip's technical datasheet.

Comment: OK, let me check where that word is defined.

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Yep, you're right `#include <xtensa/config/core.h>
#include <xtensa/tie/xt_interrupt.h>
#include <xtensa/tie/xt_timer.h>` it's xtensa.

Comment: Replay to your answer: Thanks for the explanation. But my question also is about the method of putting something after function braces in C programming rules. What does that method called ?

Comment: It’s called writing code.

Comment: It's called adding attributes to a function prototype. They can go anywhere in the prototype.

Comment: @Majenko .. dude, thank you so much. I just feel honored that you reply to me. Thanks again !

Comment: So, it can be also like this: `void vTaskDelay PRIVILEGED_FUNCTION( const TickType_t xTicksToDelay );` ? That I can add this attribute, before after the name of the function or even after the braces of function parameters, right ?

Comment: @R1S8K yep, that's right.